# I'm trying to sum up all the logs of the first 10 primes. Program not working

Tags: python-2.7

The result I'm getting after running the code in powershell is three numbers and then a freeze.

The numbers are

1.09861228867,
1.60943791243,
1.94591014906

```
#summing up all the logs of the first 10 primes, excluding 2. 

from math import *  # library imports
import math         # " " 

count = 1                       #1-9 gives us 9 primes in total
numb = 3                       #3 is the second prime number.  
logy_of_prime_sum_total = 0     #sum of log of primes starts at zero
logy = 0                        #first value of log is zero

while count != 10:              #loops 9 times, for a total of 9 primes.
    for k in range(2,numb):  #from 2 up to but not including numb. 
        if numb%k == 0:       #purpose is to skip the else if not prime.
            break             #break takes us out of the for/else disj.
    else:
        logy_of_prime_sum_total = logy+logy_of_prime_sum_total
        logy = math.log(numb)    #when the else activates, we are 
        print(logy)              #dealing with a prime, getting a value     
        numb += 2                #the log of it, incr. numb. by two, 
        count += 1               #because primes have to be odd, 
                                 #increase the count
print logy_of_prime_sum_total    #print the sum of all the logs after the 
                                #while end.
```

Comment: Your `if` does not match `else`. `for` loop is pointless as `prime` is 3 so range would be (2, 3) which is half open, half close range so basically it would be 3. You are not assigning to logy_of_prime_sum_total.

Comment: Basically it is a horrible mess.

Comment: If you explain the logic you are using to calculate the prime numbers, that would help us in helping you :)

Comment: I added as much comments as I could.

Comment: @user902384, the `else` is correctly matched up to the `for` loop. `prime` is only `3` the first time around the while loop, next it will be `5`, `7`, `9`, etc.

Comment: @AChampion `for` has an `else` counterpart. Send me to hell.

Comment: @Shubham, the OP is using a simplistic if inefficient test of check every number from `2` to `prime-1` and ensuring it doesn't divide evenly into the `prime` (the `for` loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only issue you have is you are not increasing `numb` if `numb` happens to be composite. Just move `numb += 2` to the end of the loop and unindent. When `numb` is composite, e.g. `9` (4th number) you are breaking out of the `for` loop and never incrementing `numb` (`else` on a `for` loop only executes if you don't `break`):

```
while count != 10:
    for k in range(2,numb):  #from 2 up to but not including prime. 
        if numb%k == 0:
            break
    else:
        logy_of_prime_sum_total = logy+logy_of_prime_sum_total
        logy = math.log(numb)
        print(logy)
        count += 1
    numb += 2

print(logy_of_prime_sum_total)
```

Output:

```
1.0986122886681098
1.6094379124341003
1.9459101490553132
2.3978952727983707
2.5649493574615367
2.833213344056216
2.9444389791664403
3.1354942159291497
3.367295829986474
18.529951519569238
```

BTW: You need to start the `count = 0` to get `10` numbers, you will currently only get `9`.